# Apache RewriteRule - everything except localhost and loopback

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I have a server that I want to enforce https communication to from the outside world, however, there are services on the server that need to be accessed over http by processes on the local server.

I've tried the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

But of course, services running on the local server fail to be accessed over http. How do I enforced https for everything except localhost and 127.0.0.1? Or, if easier, I have 2 external domains for this server - how do I only force https for http://sub1.domain1.suffix1 and http://sub2.domain2.suffix2 and the server's external facing IP?

Comment: please give an example of a service from 127.0.0.1, I do lots of server based requests on an https/ssl site, but they all just request via lynx to a page on the site. I'm unclear what case would involve what you are talking about.  If the two domains are being run via apache vitualhosts, you'd be setting up https per domain in the normal case, not per server, unless you have a global certificate for all subdomains of domain1 or domain2.

Comment: I'm hosting on windows azure via a VM, so I've got 2 domains - the one provided by azure (thedomain.cloudapp.net) and the one that I have my SSL cert for (mysub.mydomain.com). Nobody should be using the cloudapp.net domain, but if they do, I want to ensure I redirect them to the real SSL domain properly. I'm running mediawiki with a parsoid server located on the box. Parsoid is only accessible via the local machine but is a web service, and mediawiki is configured to access it via http://localhost/.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this, I'm not positive it will work, but it might, I've never dealt with the actual 'localhost' value.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://mysub.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

UPDATE 2: I thought about this, and realized this fails to handle this case:
https://mysub2.mydomain.com/ redirect to https://mysub.mydomain.com/ - before adding this, test that url and see if it redirects with the first rule or not, if it does not, test this second set of rules instead.

To correct this case, try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} mysub2.mydomain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://mysub.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

UPDATE2 explanation, if it works:

Make the test more complicated, now the rewrite happens if not localhost/127.0.0.1 then test not https OR is mysub2.mydomain.com (or whatever other domains/sub domains are on the server that you want to redirect to: https://mysub.mydomain.com

=UPDATE explanation:

This is a pretty simple set of rules. We create 3 conditions that must be met for the rewrite rules to apply. To be safe I use the ^ by habit, ie, that's what it starts with, so this says, host name/IP does not start with localhost/127.0.0.1. ! means not.

1. The hostname is not localhost (hostname is what you would type in your browser to access the page, or the name you'd use to access it via your web service). Because domain names are not case sensitive, I added the [NC] flag, which means No Case, ie, case insenstive. This is the one I wasn't sure would work:

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
2. The remote request IP is not 127.0.0.1

   RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127.0.0.1$
3. https is not on already

   RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on

Then the actual rewrite rule, which triggers if these three conditions are met. Rewrite all urls not including the starting /, take everything in that url (.*) which does not include the domain name and add it after https://mysub.mydomain.com/, Then do a 301 permanent redirect to that resultant full url. ? means 0 or 1. (.*) means: put everything after starting / or no starting / into $1, each (...) in the rule is put into variables $1, $2, and so on.

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://mysub.mydomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]

=END update

Your setup is not fully intuitive to me, to me, but assuming  there is only one actual domain on the server that you want to be handling requests, then this I think would work, not positive, given there's some features I'm not familiar with.

To redirect to https, all three conditions must be true, that is, not local/127, and https not on.

Comment: That did it! Thank you very much. If you have a few minutes, explaining why this works would be really helpful too.

Comment: Oh, it worked, that's good, I wasn't positive because of your setup. It's pretty simple, I'll update the answer to explain it.

Comment: Now that I think of it, you can probably remove the localhost condition, because the REMOTE_ADDR is going to be 127.0.0.1 for localhost, but I wanted to be sure since I've never dealt with that scenario. But it doesn't hurt to have it there, and on the weird off chance that localhost became not 127.0.0.1 you'd still be covered.

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^localhost [NC]
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^127\.0\.0\.1$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a slightly different case, but if you have a proxy in front of your server like a load balancer, you can do this (which is what is proposed by AWS for redirecting to TLS while behind ELB), which I thought was kind of cool once I figured out that not doing this makes my config also redirect localhost:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]
```